# why does'nt this output the max element of the vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int b;
vector<int>={32,3,4,34,32,5465,6543}
b=d[*max_element(d.begin(),d.end())];

cout << b;
}
```

why won't this code print the max element of the vector d.

Comment: The code has diagnosable errors, so will not compile, let alone output anything.

Comment: Did you mean `vector<int>d{32,3,4,34,32,5465,6543}`?

Comment: [You should never use #include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 1):

Because what `std::max_element()` returns is an *iterator*. To access the element you can *dereference* it via `*`, which is what you do, but instead of printing *that maximum value*, you use it to index the vector.

Simply output it: `std::cout << *std::max_element(d.begin(),d.end());`.